# Issues with colorbox and Jquery appendTo function

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Basically I am using JQuery and colorbox. I am using iframe class of colorbox.

So basically initiating with

```
$(".iframe44").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

I am then using it on a element as

```
<div class="class1">
<a class="iframe44" href=xyz.php> Add New</a>
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

This piece of code is fine and the iframe pop's out. The class also transforms to class=iframe44 cboxElement as expected.

So not I am running an AJAX call to get some values ( as JSON) and then using `appendTo()`to add stuff into the `<ul>` element. Like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "values.php?type=init",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (data) {
            //alert("success");
            var ul_data = '';
            var counter = 0;
            for (var val in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
                    console.log(data[counter].variable1 + data[counter].variable2);
                    ul_data = ul_data + "<li><a class=\"iframe44\" href=value_edit.php?variable2=" + data[counter].variable2 + ">" + data[counter].variable1 + "</li>";
                }
                counter++;
            }
            $(ul_data).appendTo('#class1 ul');
        }
    });
});
```

Now the issue I am facing is that the newly appended ul_data into the `<div>` does not have the same characteristics of class=iframe44 cboxElement ... rather it has is class=iframe44, and hence the popup is not coming.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong? Why is the class of appended data not coming correctly.

Any help appreciated !!!

Comment: add `$(".iframe44").colorbox..` after `$(ul_data).appendTo('#class1 ul');`

Comment: What @mgraph said is correct. To explain further, the `$(".iframe44").colorbox(...)` command is procedural, not declarative. It runs on *existing* elements at the time you run it. It won't effect elements you add in the future. To get it to work on those elements, you have to run it again after adding them (preferably, limit your scope down to the newly added elements though, rather than doing the whole set of `.iframe44` over each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
$(".iframe44").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

after

```
$(ul_data).appendTo('.class1 ul');
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that. It did not work ... Also, if you look, I am declaring the iframe44 before the first instance of "a class=iframe" .....

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the issue as there is no `id` with `"Class1"`

```
 $(ul_data).appendTo('#class1 ul');//Wrong

 $(ul_data).appendTo('.class1 ul');//Right
```

Comment: Sorry, a typo... I correct the earlier code from <div class="class1">
 to <div id="class1"> in the actual code ...Still no luck !!